# How to calculate Z when doing Bernoulli differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm just learning how to do a Bernoulli differential equation and I'm stuck at the part where you have to use Z (others call it U).

For example:

When (y^-3)y' + (1/2x)y^-2 = -(1/2)X² * sin²x*cosx

Then your Z equals (1/(1-3))y^1-3 = (-1/2)y^-2
Then you have to calculate z' and that is where my problem is. 
I would say Z' = (-1/2)*(-2)*y^-3 = y^-3.

However, it seems that the solution is (y^-3)*y'. In all those exercises in my course, they always multiply with y'. Why is that? I don't get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

You're forming the derivative of $z$ with respect to $y$. But a prime is usually used to denote the derivative with respect to $x$. (Indeed the differential equation wouldn't make sense if the prime were intended to denote differentiation with respect to $y$, since $y'$ would then just be $1$.)

So $z'$ is the derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$, not to $y$, and by the chain rule this is the derivative of $z$ with respect to $y$ times the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$. Since you already calculated the derivative of $z$ with respect to $y$, all you have to do is multiply it by the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, which is $y'$.